# Refactoring the tiny code that handles "overrides of default parameters"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python(2.7) class that wraps up calling some bash commands. What is important here is that it is expected that those commands called underneath need to have a lot of parameters passed to them. That is why I want to allow setting those parameters in the constructor of the class, which *vast oversimplification* looks like this:

```py
    def __init__(self, foo=None, baz=None, bar=None):
        self._executor = BashExecutor()

        self._foo = foo
        self._baz = baz
        self._bar = bar
```

This class has also some functions that allow overriding those parameters (but doesn't force it) in scope of one bash execution. This means that function signatures *can* look like this:

```py
def execute(self, foo=None, baz=None, bar=None, sup=None):
```

then comes the "problematic part". Each of the parameters can be either passed in the scope of a function, given in a constructor of the object or not passed at all (Passing it in function has higher precedence over constructor). Thus I have a following snippets of code:

```py
foo = foo or self._foo
if foo:
  params.append(<<somehow formatted foo>>)
```

Those are just 3 lines, but they are repeated many times with different parameters that have different formatting...

Couldn't this be simplified somehow?

The complete example that illustrates the problem looks as follows:

```py
class BashExecutor(object):
    def execute(self, command):
        print command

class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, foo=None, baz=None, bar=None):
        self._executor = BashExecutor()

        self._foo = foo
        self._baz = baz
        self._bar = bar

    def execute(self, foo=None, baz=None, bar=None, sup=None):
        params = []

        foo = foo or self._foo
        if foo:
            params.append("--foo_param %s" % foo)

        baz = baz or self._baz
        if baz:
            params.append("--baz_param %s" % baz)

        bar = bar or self._bar
        if bar:
            params.append("--additional_param bar=%s" % bar)

        sup = sup or []
        if sup:
            params.append("--additional_param sup=%s" % ",".join(sup))

        self._executor.execute("application %s" % " ".join(params))

ex = Example(foo=1, bar=2)

ex.execute(foo=3, sup=[ "abc", "def" ])
```

Comment: What differentiates "param" and "additional_param"?

Comment: Here, nothing (that is the weakness of this example). In real life I have a function `execute` that can accept `user` and `vars` parameters. Bash command underneath requires user to be passed as `--user %s` and vars needs to be dumped to json before being passed with `--extra-vars` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
class Solution(object):    

    _ALLOWED_USER = ['cake', 'chocolate', 'creme_brulee']
    _ALLOWED_VARS = ['broccoli', 'avocado', 'spinach']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._validate_kwargs(kwargs)
        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, '_{}'.format(key), value)

    def _validate_kwargs(self, kwargs):
        unrecognised = {key for key in kwargs if key not in self._ALLOWED_USER + self._ALLOWED_VARS}
        if unrecognised:
            raise ValueError('The following unrecognised arguments were passed: {}'.format(unrecognised))

    def _populate(self, iterable, allowed, format_string):
        result = []
        for key in allowed:
            attribute_name = '_{}'.format(key)
            if key in iterable:
                result.append(format_string.format(key, iterable[key]))

            elif hasattr(self, attribute_name):
                result.append(format_string.format(key, getattr(self, attribute_name)))

        return result

    def execute(self, **kwargs):
        self._validate_kwargs(kwargs)
        user_args = self._populate(kwargs, self._ALLOWED_USER, '--{}_param {}')
        vars_args = self._populate(kwargs, self._ALLOWED_VARS, '--additional_param {}={}')
        print(user_args + vars_args)

my_solution = Solution(cake='tasty', broccoli='icky', avocado='awesome')
my_solution.execute(creme_brulee='great', broccoli='okay, I guess', spinach='meh', cake='really tasty')
```

Output:

```
['--cake_param really tasty', '--creme_brulee_param great', '--additional_param broccoli=okay, I guess', '--additional_param avocado=awesome', '--additional_param spinach=meh']
```

You can see that the instance values for `cake` and `broccoli` have been overridden by those passed to the function.

The idea is basically to factor out what is constant among all relevant paths, and to provide customisability through arguments. By separating `user` arguments from `vars` arguments and using `**kwargs`, we can achieve input validation in tandem with flexibility *and* a different output for each type of argument.

The behaviour of arguments overriding instance variables can be done by checking for the presence of each argument in the passed arguments first, and then in the attributes of the instance, using `hasattr`.

I don't have access to Python 2 right now, but this *should* work.